# Есть ли такой термин стихосложения "палефлем"?

Tags: литература

Есть ли такой термин стихосложения "палефлем"?

Comment: Это вопрос из вступительного теста в вуз. Может, в слове опечатка?

Comment: Так приведите весь текст. Почти наверняка это действительно "опечатка"  (если так можно назвать ошибку), но какая - гадать очень сложно, не имея контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, *палефлем* – это выдуманный термин для проверки на тестах и экзаменах.

По состоянию на 28 июля 2019 года, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC) выдает всего 3 результата, из которых все, кроме одного ведут на этот вопрос. Единственная внешняя ссылка - это [Telegram-канал ruslitekzamen](https://ru.tgchannels.org/channel/ruslitekzamen/447), в котором 23 апреля 2019 года опубликовали опрос:

> Назовите одно из сильнейших средств сатиры, злая и язвительная насмешка - издевка, высшая степень иронии: сарказм (106), **палефлем (1)**, юмор (3), гротеск (2).

Что тоже, в общем-то, свидетельствует не в пользу существования этого термина.

Также можно посмотреть авторитетный ["Поэтический словарь" А. П. Квятковского](http://feb-web.ru/feb/kps/kps-abc/), в котором этот термин отсутсвует (так же как и возможные похожие написания связанные с теоретической возможностью опечатки). Более того, при беглом поиске я не нашел в словарях ни одного слова, оканчивающегося на *-флем*, что также говорит в пользу его выдуманности.